# Why has my nomination to the 2021 Moderator Election been withdrawn without my consent?

Tags: support

My nomination has disappeared.

There is a message stating that "Candidate’s nomination was withdrawn 23 hours ago. Any votes for this candidate will not be counted."

https://iota.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1

What has happened? I have not withdrawn my nomination. Who has done it? the IOTA StackExchange moderators? StackExchange?

Answer (score 5):

It was not us moderators. Moderators have no power on moderating moderator elections (by design).

Assuming it was not yourself who withdrew your nomination, you'd have to ask the StackExchange Community Management team (via the Contact form linked below).

Comment: The community might have added flags to his nomination. But I am not sure who deals with those.

Comment: @TobiMZ When you click the Flag button you will see that the Community Management team will (have to) deal with them.

Comment: only if you pick the option for community management. What if other oprions are clicked?

Comment: Hmm, you mean when you do not click "A problem not listed above that requires action by a community manager."? What do you believe happens when you flag a normal post and do not select "A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator."? [I guess I don't tell any secrets that hey land in the moderator flag queue as well, just grouped by reasons]